# Prevent Jump to Top of Page When Clicking Link

Tags: php, html, ajax, hyperlink

I have been stuck on how to prevent jumping to the top of the page when clicking on a link that has parsing PHP data.

I have tried so many AJAX examples off the internet, but unfortunately with no success.

A link looks like this:

```
<a class="bottle" href="index.php?step=<?php echo$step; ?>&bottle=b0"><img class="bottle" src="images/b0.jpg" /></a>
```

...with there being 113 of these links, each staying on index.php?, but jumping to the top of the page when clicked.

A preview of the program is: http://www.mtschools.net/aurasoma

Comment: It doesn't "jump" to the top of the page, it reloads the page every time. You need to think and reconstruct your code in such a manner that it will collect all needed information before reloading the page. JavaScript is probably what you want to use.

Comment: Put ONCLICK event in the image and do the AJAX CALL!

Comment: onclick="return false;" it's help

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the `preventDefault();` method in javascript to stop the browser from following through with the anchor links href location.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.bottle');
    for(var i = 0; i < links; i++){
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //alternatively return false;

            //the rest of the ajax code here.
        });
    }
</script>
```

Whatever ajax call you need to make can be done after `//the rest of the ajax code here`.

Answer (score 0):

User a link without HREF, and then set CSS cursor to be pointer either with jQuery or CSS.

This to make clickable sort of link. Not entire solution to your problem.

But you could also have an anchor with the name, so when you click, you will move to the anchor and perhaps stay on the anchor, instead of the top of the page?

```
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        ('#link').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });
</script>

<a id="link">Some Text</a>
```